# Check via RegEx if string contains only Slash(es)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want check if a given string contains only `/` but any number of occurrences of that. If it's an empty string it should return false.

**Examples:**

```
//dlkw8923   => false
9            => false
()           => false
lasdf//asdf  => false
/            => true
///          => true
//           => true
/   /        => true (this case is not that important... it does not matter if it doesn't match)
```

**What I tried so far:**

```
^[/]+$
^[\/]+$
^[\//]+$
^\/+$
```

I used [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test, but none of it worked.

What did I miss? How can i check if the entire string is made up of `/`?

Comment: You forgot to use `m` modifier. Your patterns work as expected if you test against  a separate string.

Comment: You last pattern will work: `"/".match(/^\/+$/)` The default flags on regex101.com are g and m, and it works of both are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex, which will match all that should be matched, incl. the last line:

```
/^[\/][\/ ]*$/gm
```

It starts by matching a slash `'/'`, followed by either slashes `'/'` or `Spaces` until the end of line.

Comment: Especially when notating the regex as `/../`-syntax you should escape the backslashes.